# Deriving conditions positive semidefiniteness Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, positive-semidefinite

I am currently struggling to calculate the following conditions (marked in yellow) for the positive semidefiniteness of the matrix $G$ in (2.1). From a paper, I am reading:

[image]

Note that $\Sigma$ is assumed to be positive semidefinite.

I understand how to get from (2.1) to (2.2) by calculating the Schur complement. We can also see that $A$ is the Schur complement of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & diag(s) \\
diag(s) & 2diag(s) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

by just applying the formula for the Schur complement "backwards". However, I don't understand how to derive from there the last two final conditions marked in yellow, i.e. how to show that $A \succeq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a direct application of a (non-strict) Schur complement, but this time over the diagonal matrix instead of $\Sigma$.

With $S = diag(s)$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & S\\
S & 2S
\end{bmatrix} \Leftrightarrow \Sigma -  S\left(2S \right)^{\dagger}S\succeq 0,  ~S\succeq 0, (I-SS^{\dagger})S=0$$

Simplify exploiting the simple structure and you are done.

Comment: Thanks ! That has helped a lot. One question where does your second condition comes from ? Looking at the PSD requirement of a Schur complement, doesn't we need to require that $diag(s) \succ 0$ ?

Comment: Yes it is a bit sloppy (as you cannot optimize over strict inequality anyway in practice). The non-strict cases requires a third condition to be complete  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: Yes, I was exactly referring to Wikipedia's part about PSD there: "If C is positive definite, then X is positive semi-definite if and only if the complement X/C is positive semi-definite:". Hence, my comment about the strictness (in case thas diag(s) is our C)